# fetch проблема с передачей файла

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch

Хочу передать файл,
форма такая

```html
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" id="logo" @change="LogoUpload($event.target.files)"></form>
```

Метод не замысловат

```js
let form = new FormData();
form.append("file",files[0]);
fetch("http://127.0.0.1",{method:'post',headers:{"Content-type":"multipart/form-data"}, body : form});
```

проблема в том что не передается содержимое

```html
------WebKitFormBoundary9wcnRDYkOAFMdLOo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a9J63zXOn8s.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9wcnRDYkOAFMdLOo--
```

через axios тоже пробовал, рузельтат такой же.

Comment: а пробовали не устанавливать `Content-type`, через `XMLHttpRequest` я не устанавливаю этот заголовок

Comment: Кстати здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch пример, где `fetch` + `FormData` тоже без `Content-type`

Comment: да пробовал и без Content-type, результат тодже самый, мистика прям какаето